# What's React's "$emit" as in Angular world

Tags: angularjs, events, reactjs, emit

In Angular, we could use the $scope.$emit method to notify ancestors. How can we do the same thing in React?

Comment: Are you trying to trigger a certain lifecycle event or function belonging to a class of an ancestor?

Comment: Yes. Imagine that I have a deep view tree. In one leaf node there is a button, when this button is clicked, I need the root view to switch to a new view.

Comment: I don't think there is a such thing as emit. React is a very different way of thinking. The state should be getting passed through these ancestors till it reaches the button. So in that ancestor that control view it would see that a new state and switch the view. This is what I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trivial solution is to pass a callback from parent to child to grandchild, etc... When the descent invokes the callback, it will be run in the context of the parent.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.click = this.click.bind(this); // bind the handler to this
  }
  
  click(view) {
    this.setState({ view }); // change the state
  }
  
  render() {
    return <Child clickHandler={ this.click } />; // pass CB to child
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <GrandChild clickHandler={ this.props.clickHandler } />;  // pass CB to grandChild
  }
}

class GrandChild extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <button onClick={ () => this.props.clickHandler('nextViewId') }>Click</button>; // invoke CB on click
  }
}
```

The problem is that if you have a large tree of components, you'll have to transfer multiple callbacks to multiple levels. Which means that every container can have multiple properties, that just pass CBs around, making testing and maintenance really hard. Use this solution for small apps.

For large applications you should use a [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) based architecture, such as [redux](http://redux.js.org/). The rough idea is that every action is dispatched by the invoking component, and handled by a main store, which creates a new model, and transfer it to the root of the components tree. In this way, every component gets all the data that it needs, and can handle it however it wishes. This will feel a bit like using Angular's $broadcast to the root.